# How to show Count Data in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Im new in Laravel, 5 hours i have tried to adding this function and im so confused. 
**Case :**
I want to show count data in table `tb_surat` in dashboard (i used sximo) 
ex, if in `tb_surat` i have **12 row** data. how to show this like 
**"Total data : 12"**

help me please, give me step by step to adding in controller or view or route or etc, i dont understand. thanks.

Comment: I think your problem is not in this single method, but its in "i dont understand".

You can start laravel step-by-step learning here: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch (need a $9 per month subscription for some videos, but it WORTHS it). Or https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart

Answer (score 9):

You can use the query builder in this way:

```
 DB::table('tb_surat')->count()
```

Answer (score 6):

I would strongly recommend you to use Eloquent way. It is as simple as below

**Step 1 :**

Create a Model

`php artisan make:model Surat`

**Step 2 :**

Inside the Model name the table by

`protected $table = 'tb_surat';`

then simply

`Surat::count();`

Then as if you need to pass the result in your view simply pass it from the controller like

```
$count = Surat::count();
return View::make('index')->with('count', $count);
```

Where your view will have

`Total data : {{$count}}`

**Note :**

1. The reason why i recommend you to use model is to follow the Eloquent way as it was the best practise ever.
2. It would be better if you have a fresh start with the [Laravel Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3)

Answer (score 0):

write the code hope u will find answer

```
<?php
            $count = DB::table('fulldataviews')->count();
            echo '<h3>'.$count.'</h3>';
            ?>
```